# What is the best practice to use Bluemix autoscaling and Node.js cluster method

Tags: node.js, express, jenkins, ibm-cloud, devops

I've changed my simple Node.js/Express app to use cluster module:
https://rowanmanning.com/posts/node-cluster-and-express/

and it works perfect on my local. Now what if I deploy it to Cloud? How should autoscaling.json and manifest.yml files be adjusted so it doesn't conflict with that multithreading implementation?

manifest.yml

```
---
applications:
- name: my service
  host: xxxxxxxxxx
  memory: 512M
  path: ../../.
  timeout: 180
  instances: 3
  disk_quota: 1024M
```

autoscaling.json

```
{
  "instanceMaxCount": 5,
  "instanceMinCount": 3,
  "policyTriggers": [
    {
      "breachDuration": 600,
      "instanceStepCountDown": 1,
      "instanceStepCountUp": 1,
      "lowerThreshold": 35,
      "metricType": "Memory",
      "statWindow": 300,
      "stepDownCoolDownSecs": 600,
      "stepUpCoolDownSecs": 600,
      "upperThreshold": 70
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did anybody try to run node-cluster app in AWS or Bluemix?

Comment: How do you deploy to IBM Cloud? Are you using the Cloud Foundry service within IBM cloud? Or a different compute service?